# I want to change the div size when I press a specific letter on the keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

index.html

```
<body id="body">
  <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

style.css

```
.box {

  padding: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

I try with JavaScript to do some function when you press "e" on the keyboard that you automatically add +10 px to the div (box) size.
It' s look like this :

main.js

```
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
  switch (key) {
    case 81:
      var main = document.getElementsByClassName('box').offsetHeight;
      var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('box').offsetWidth;
      main += 10 +'px';
      sidebar += 10 +'px'
      break;
    default:
      console.log('option no valid!');
  }
};
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a variety of things wrong with your code...

First, you calculations to adjust `main` and `sidebar` were incorrect and would result in concatenation, rather than  addition.

Also, you weren't doing anything with the newly calculated values. Just becuase you set a variable equal to a property doesn't mean that you have two-way binding to that property. All you are doing is getting the value. If you want to set a value, you have to write back to the property. I assume you wanted to change the `height` and `width` of the box (`offsetheight` and `offsetwidth` are read-only).

Next, when you search for an element using `querySelectorAll()`, it will return an array-like object containing all the elements that match the query, you must grab the element that you wish to use out of the collection with an index. If you are only expecting to find one element with your query, use `querySelector()` instead of `querySelectorAll()` as `querySelector()` returns a reference to the found element directly (so no index is needed) and then stops searching.

Next, the `e` key code is 69, not 81.

```js
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
  console.log("Key code is: " + key + " - Key pressed was: " + String.fromCharCode(key));
  switch (key) {
    case 69:
        // Note the [0] at the end of this line to extract the first
        // element in the set of matched elments.
        var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
      
        // Get the values you need
        var main = box.offsetHeight;
        var sidebar = box.offsetWidth;
      
        // Do the math first, then concatenate the "px" and assign the answer back to the variable
        main = (main + 10) +'px';
        sidebar = (sidebar + 10) +'px'
        
        // Now use the new values by assigning them to the correct properties of the object:
        box.style.height = main;
        box.style.width = sidebar;
        break;
    default:
      console.log('option no valid!');
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent! thaks a lot for your advices! I appreciate, thanx!